# invoking an intent using html link

Tags: android, html, android-intent

I am trying to implement a new feature for my android application.

scenario :

when some event occurs, the camera sends an email to my (Gmail) account.

on opening the mail, it will have a link (html).
when user clicks on that link, it should launch my application Home activity.

I need to understand :

1. how to create that html link.
2. how can i make the link to launch my application Home activity.

kindly help me to understand what all things i need to do in my application.

I used "Blackbelt's" user comment and i was able to get the intent html link working.

But my problem is :  i want to use a custom scheme "mobile"  instead of "http"

I am using Gmail to use the link. But when i send using custom scheme. Gmail doesnt recogonise as hyperlink. So i cannot click on the link.

Please help me how to use a custom scheme. with gmail

Comment: what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to register an `intent-filter` for your `Activity` on the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, defining a custom url. . E.g.

```
<activity android:name="path.to.YourActivity" > 
    <intent-filter> 
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
         <data android:scheme="https"
             android:host="it.is.my.app" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

So if you press on a link like `https://it.is.my.app`, you should be prompted with the android intent chooser, with your app